# Json to objects in Java (Gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to create objects with this JSON:

```
{
"data": {
  "Prueba1": {
     "id": 266,
     "title": "Prueba1",
     "name": "Prueba1",
     "key": "Prueba1",
     "lore": "Prueba1"
  },
  "Prueba2": {
     "id": 111,
     "title": "Prueba2",
     "name": "Prueba2",
     "key": "Prueba2",
     "lore": "Prueba2"
  }
 },
"type": "prueba",
"version": "1.0"
}
```

The problem is that Gson is giving me the object 'data' but I can't not conver it to an array of objects.

My actual code is:

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("route to archive json");
    JsonElement datos = parser.parse(fr);
    JsonElement heroes = datos.getAsJsonObject().get("data");

   final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Type tipoListaEmpleados = new TypeToken<List<hero>>(){}.getType();
    final List<hero> hero = gson.fromJson(heroes, tipoListaEmpleados);

    System.out.println(hero.get(2));
```

But it's throwing error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $
```

Any tip about the problem would be appreciated.

P.S: I understand that is giving all object, but I don't get the point of why is this happening, please help!!

EDIT: I'm working with an external API, that gives me that result, so I can't change the rest response, I need to convert to objects without adding []

EDIT2: Hero class looks like a single POJO :

```
public class hero
{
public int id;
public String title;
public String name;
public String key;
public String lore;
//constructor getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have `[` and `]` if it's mention to be array of objects? It looks like a map to me.

Comment: It's an object with objects, it can't be possible??

Comment: The outer element in your sample JSON is an object with `{}`. But you are trying to deserialize a `List<hero>` which would expect the outer element to be an array with `[]`. This is why you're getting that error message.

Comment: The issue may be that you're trying to parse a single JSON object into a `List<hero>`. You haven't shown us what `Hero` looks like but there's no array to convert into a `List` in your JSON.

Comment: Having `Prueba1` and `Prueba2` let me thing those two should be in an array without the `Prueba` name for each element. Hving something like `{"data":[{"id":266,...},{"id":111}]}`

Comment: What is the API that your are using and could you have a Preuba3 or only 1 object ?

Comment: Is the League Of Legends API, there are a lot of pruebas more we can say :D

Comment: I can't say for sure you will be able to use the GSON builders to create a List without receiving an array. You are going to need to iterate on the data keys to find every item and create an instance of Hero depending on that. Don't have the time to write that but you should be able to find that on SO (Note : That's a wrong design for an API... A list should be converted in an Array ... not as a plain object with dynamic number of item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't actually have a JSON Array in it. Try this...although this might not be the exact structure you're looking for.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Prueba1": {
            "id": 266,
            "title": "Prueba1",
            "name": "Prueba1",
            "key": "Prueba1",
            "lore": "Prueba1"
        },
        "Prueba2": {
            "id": 111,
            "title": "Prueba2",
            "name": "Prueba2",
            "key": "Prueba2",
            "lore": "Prueba2"
        }
    }],
    "type": "prueba",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

You can use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to verify your JSON and tweak accordingly

Comment: I tried with this JSON, but still not working with the code I posted in the question =D

Comment: @JotaGe you'll probably have to use this line too instead 
`JsonElement heroes = datos.getAsJsonArray().get("data");`

Comment: Yes, I have that line

Comment: No, you're getting it as an object and using `JsonElement heroes = datos.getAsJsonObject().get("data");`

Comment: Also, where is `elemento` in `final List<hero> hero = gson.fromJson(elemento, tipoListaEmpleados);` coming from?

Comment: Elemento is heroes object

Comment: Using this structure without the names, it work, thanks!!